# jQuery Mobile, setting the slider's value

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, uislider

The slider currently renders fine, it just doesn't do what I tell it to.

I can't use `$('#slider').val(50).slider('refresh')`, and 
when I do it tells me:

> Uncaught cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'refresh'

Which, seems to make sense, since I never initialized it as a slider. Here is my code:
Somewhere earlier I create a div `"<div id='scrubber'></div>"` and just write it to the screen  `$(cssSelector.html(html);` Then once some other part of the code is ready I create the slider:

```
$('#scrubber').html('<input type="range" name="prog" id="prog" value="0" min="0" max="'+event.jPlayer.status.duration+'"  />').trigger("create");
```

Then later:

```
$('#scrubber').val(event.jPlayer.status.currentTime).slider('refresh');
```

Which gives me that error.

I have tried using `$('#scrubber').slider();` but that seems to create a 2nd slider. So then I tried to replace the first slider, but it just messes things up even more. In any case, if I then try to change the value, I no longer get the error, but it still doesn't change the slider's position.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't worked on jQM for a while, but does it still have the .page() function?
If so call page() on the sliders wrapper:

```
('#scrubber').parent().page();
$('#scrubber').val(event.jPlayer.status.currentTime).slider('refresh');
```

This will re-render the slider, causing it to be properly initialised.

Comment: This some how lead me to the answer, which was: $("input[type=number]").val(60).slider('refresh');

It would seem JQM relies on the number in the text number field to move the scroller.